# What's the difference between .npmignore and .gitignore?

Tags: git, npm, gitignore, npmignore

What's the difference between `.npmignore` and `.gitignore`? What kind of files should I ignore in each?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`.gitignore` lists which files & folders should be omitted from any commits to the repository. You can use [this repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for templates of files/folders to in your `.gitignore` depending on your environment.

`.npmignore` works similarly to `.gitignore`, it is used to specify which files should be omitted when publishing the package to NPM. You can read more about it in the [`.npmignore` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)