# Hide folders with npm

Tags: git, npm, repository

Is it possible not to make available all folders with npm ?

I have a git repository with :

```
MyRepo
|- library
|- FolderToHide
|- package.json
```

File package.json is containing :

```
{
   "name": "myRepo",
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "https://somewhere"
   },
   ...
}
```

And a have a second repository containing a package.json file :

```
{
   "name": "myRepo2",
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "https://somewhereelse"
   },
   dependencies": {
     "myRepo": "git+ssh:https://git@somewhere"
   }
   ...
}
```

But nodemodules in myRepo2 is containing myRepos/FolderToHide. How can I configure myRepo to make available only some folders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.npmignore` to control the files and folders which will be installed when another repository installs your package via npm. Check the difference of `.npmignore` and `.gitignore` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765914/whats-the-difference-between-npmignore-and-gitignore) .

1. Create the `.npmignore` file in the root folder of **myRepo**.
2. Inside the file, paste this `FolderToHide/` and save it.
3. Now update the `package.json` **myRepo** to whitelist the folders you want to publish.

   ```
     `        "files": [
                 "library/"
               ]`
   ```
4. Now your **myRepo2** can download and install the updated npm packages from **myRepo**

Refer this also for a better understanding.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this can be optional ? Can I have a myRepo3 that can access to FolderToHide ?

Comment: using this method you would not be able to do that.